# How to find last listview item & add dynamic view after that in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm developing an Android application which has a custom list-view of dynamic values. In that, I need to find out the last list-view item and after that I need to add a dynamic text-view. For example, I'm creating a custom adapter which I passed array of values such as item1, item2, item3. While display, listview should be

```
item1
item2
item3
count=3 -- my dynamic textview should come here.
```

If I add another array element as item4,listview should be:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
count=4 -- my dynamic view.
```

Below code show all arraylist values well. But its not showing the count view. How could I do that?

My LazyAdapter:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare variables
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> filepath;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> imageUri) {//Here i passed dynamic //values from my MainActivity.
        activity = a;
        filepath = imageUri;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filepath.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextView in gridview_item.xml
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);

        if (position == getCount()) {
            text.setText("Count=" + getCount());

        } else {
            text.setText(filepath.get(position));

        }

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add a footer to your ListView using [addFooterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)). A footer always stays at the bottom of your list.

PS: Make sure you add the footer BEFORE you set the adapter. Otherwise the footer will not show.